# Multiple linear videos using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I managed to play a clip after a previous clip, but how do you add on to more after the second clip has ended? Is it possible to assign a video list to an array and create an 'if' statement? What would be the best way to play more than 2 videos in a sequence?
Many thanks.

```
var myVideo = _V_("vid1");


function onComplete1(){

    var video2 = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var videoPlaying = video2.currentSrc;
    var ext = videoPlaying.substr(videoPlaying.lastIndexOf("."));

    video2.src = '2'+ext;

    myVideo.load();
    myVideo.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

No video for me to test, but you may consider this:

```js
(function(){
  var seq=["1.ogg","2.ogg"/* more */];
  var pos=0;
  var video=document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  function onComplete() {
    if(pos>=seq.length) pos=-1; //if you want to loop
    if(pos>=seq.length) return; //if you don't want to loop
    video.src=seq[++pos];
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }
  video.onended=onComplete;
  video.src=seq[pos];
  video.load();
  video.play();
})();
```

Comment: for some reason it only plays the first video with your code, do I need to make any change to my html as well?

Comment: @user1815422 That depends. Are you using `<video src="...">` or `<video><source src="..."></video>`? Do you see some error on browser console?